# Bootstrapping new node time/issues

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have an existing 3 node Cassandra cluster. Added 3 new nodes to the cluster. The nodes are still "bootstrapping", but I added the nodes 3 days ago. I'm really concerned about this process.

1) How long does bootstrapping typically take? We have about 40GB on each node.

2) All of the new nodes have died at least once during bootstrapping with no cause given in the logs. Are there any known issues around this?

Using Cassandra 2.0.6 on Ubuntu 12.04. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this blog post (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/streaming-in-cassandra-2-0), and see what you can find out about the status and history of streaming associated with the bootstrap. It's likely it hung for some reason, but I'd like to see what happened before recommending you try it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually Bootstrapping is process to communicate the brand new node to the existing nodes in a cluster. It is recommended to allow 2-3 minutes to complete the bootstrapping process.
2. Do the new nodes have the same cassandra configuration ? While adding a new node, from the console you can run **nodetool cfstats** command to check either any streams going on.